# looking word for: current state or the state before a change

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word referring to this description: "current state of a situation or the state before situation changed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more explanation of what your looking for, but my guess is you want the **status quo**

> the existing state of affairs (e.g. seeks to preserve the status quo)

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status%20quo)

Comment: That's true. According to Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary : "the situation as it is now, or as it was before a recent change”

Comment: This would be even more apropos if given in its full form, the *status quo ante*.